# PyQT Editor for XML Configuration Files - tools/components?

Tags: xml, user-interface, pyqt

We have a program that stores in configuration across several XML files.

Originally, my plan was to write an Elixir (http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki) model to represent our configuration, write a PyQT GUI wrapper around this, and have the program export to XML when finished.

The database/Elixir layer would make it easier to validate certain things, and to represent certain relational structures in the configuration (e.g. user accounts).

However, the preference is now to just write a direct wrapper around the XML files themselves.

So my question is, what sort of tools can I use to make it easier to write a PyQT based GUI editor for XML files?

We have the XSD files for the configuration, and on the validation front, I know can use QtXMLPatterns to validate the schema:

http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/02/03/w3c-xml-schema-validation-with-qt/
http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/07/31/qt-46-with-xml-schema-support/

However, are there any shortcuts, libraries or components/tools available in PyQT to writing the actual GUI itself?

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: I have the same issue, did you get the answer? if yes, can you post here, please?